# Create Stream<T> from single object

Tags: java, java-stream

How can you create Stream from single object? Such basic operation shown to be problematic in stream API. To illustrate, I would like to complete following method meaningfully

```
private Node parent;
private List<Node> children;
public Stream<Node> getFilteredNodes(Options o) {
    if(o.findParent()/*special case*/) return /*??? stream containing just parent*/;
    return children.stream().filter(x -> x.getName().equals(o.getQuery()));
}
```

or in other words, I would like something like LINQs `return Enumerable.Repeat(parent,1);`. Even though storing `parent` in a list with single item would work, it would also complicate other logic so I would prefer using built-in methods.

---

As for what I need it for - consistency of search API, so I could search up and down hierarchy(and combine both) with same method calls, piping it to next stage.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There a method for that :

```
 Stream.of(YourObject)
```

I am just wondering of you actually need the single element Stream here, since there is a Stream constructor that takes a var arg as argument, you can just return the stream of a single element or multiple ones by a single return statement.

Comment: Simple - I cannot explain why my google search did not find this(maybe makes sense to use different keywords?). Thanks for the reply, accepting in 10 mins.

Comment: There is an overloaded factory method for creating single-argument stream:      `public static<T> Stream<T> of(T t) ` (Returns a sequential `Stream` containing a single element.)

Comment: This does not work if `YourObject` is an array.

Comment: Also see `Stream.ofNullable(yourObject)` (available since Java 9) when `yourObject` might be `null`, to be able to return an empty stream.